# How to make users to add their own contents in the custom tab, which was created by me?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

I have created an  application with custom tabs for users, so i was success in making users to add my custom tabs, but their occurred a problem,

Under my users request i have added wymeditor into that custom tab, where we then click on edit tab in that iframe their opens that editor where they can added their images or links into that tab frame. But im wandering like when they click on  the save button , the contentes which they added should be saved in that custom tab frame..

how to call the $ signed_request for that user to make them add at that custom tab frame.

`<form action="http://xxxx.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type='hidden' name='signed_request' value='VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST' />`

Comment: Could you place the signed_request into a session variable rather than putting it back into the form data?

Answer (score 0):

As @DMCS wrote, you should not repost the signed request, but instead save the data in the session.

More than that, it makes no sense to want to keep the signed request to begin with.  when you get the signed request, you decode it to extract user info, including the access token, that decoded user data is what you want to keep, otherwise you'll have to decode the signed request all over again, should be enough to do it just once

Comment: Thank you, but can you help me with any type of code or example for my clear understanding..

Comment: I have no idea how you are going about this, and with what programming language/framework you are doing it.  The official documentation explain the authentication process very well and have code snippets for it all, try this tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ which explains the authentication process (client and server side) and this tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ which explains the signed request part.